# Adding PHP code in extension after every nth list element in TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3

I'm using old fashion way (kickstarter) to build extension in TYPO3. I would like to ad some PHP code after third element of list, but I really don't know how to do this.

My code looks like that:

```
protected function makeList($res) {
    $items = array();
        // Make list table rows
    while (($this->internal['currentRow'] = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res)) !== FALSE) {
        $items[] = $this->makeListItem();
    }

    $out = '<div' . $this->pi_classParam('listrow') . '>list items</div>';
    return $out;
}
```

And:

```
protected function makeListItem() {
    $out = 'list item details';
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you would need something like this:

```
protected function makeList($res) {
    $items = array();
    // Make list table rows
    $i = 0;
    $out = '<div' . $this->pi_classParam('listrow') . '>';
    while (($this->internal['currentRow'] = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res)) !== FALSE) {

        $out .= $this->makeListItem();
        $i++;
        if ($i == 3) {
             $out .= '<img src="whateverjpg">';
             $i = 0; // if you want to do it every 3 images
        }            
    }


    $out .= '</div>';
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: This code insert the `php code` on top of page (before source code)

Comment: If what you want is to print something like html, is better if you add this logic to the view (since it looks like it is view logic).
Actually you could move all logic to the view, and pass the $items to the view.
Maybe I don't understand exactly what you want to achieve, so if you give me more information, I might help you better. :)

Comment: The extension generation list of elements, and I would like to insert image after nth list item.

Comment: As I said it would be better if you pass the $items array to the view, and do that on the view. Still, I edited the code to do what I think you want to do.
This code would create a list into the div "listrow" and every 3 items it would add an image, as long as makeListItem creates the item of the list.